# Is there a way to prevent rubber banding but still allow "click" events?

Tags: javascript, ios, coffeescript, html, hammer.js

I'm building an html 5 game and I've just started testing it out on my iPad (iOS 6, I believe, definitely not iOS 7).  When I'm playing the game, I want to avoid rubber banding but I also want to react to swipe events.  Here's how I've done this:

```
$("#game").on("touchmove", false) #prevent rubber banding on iOS
hammer = $('#game').hammer({swipe_velocity: .05})
hammer.on "swipeup", (event) -> root.core.handleKeyDown(root.constants.UP); stopProp(event)
hammer.on "swipedown", (event) -> root.core.handleKeyDown(root.constants.DOWN); stopProp(event)
hammer.on "swipeleft", (event) -> root.core.handleKeyDown(root.constants.LEFT); stopProp(event)
hammer.on "swiperight", (event) -> root.core.handleKeyDown(root.constants.RIGHT); stopProp(event)
```

The problem is, I want people to be able to click on the #game and have it pause.  The first line of my code seems to get in the way of this and I'd like to understand why.  My game event listener is listening for "click" events like this:

```
$("#game").on "click", (event) ->
```

The weird thing is that it works "sometimes" if I "try real hard".  I don't know why this is.  But if I press it many times it eventually works.

Another weird thing is that if I comment out the first line, clicking pauses the game, but it always seems to have a half second delay.  And I don't think this is for performance reasons because swiping is very responsive.

Can someone explain how to avoid rubber banding *and* allow click events to be handled?  Also explain the mistake I'm making?  I don't understand how "click" and "tap" and "mousedown" and "touch" all work together.

Comment: Are you porting natively to iOS or just running in the browser?

Comment: @Grant Just running in the safari browser on the iPad.  Is there more appropriate tags to use?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this official tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6

> add a dummy onclick handler, `onclick = "void(0)"`, so that Safari on iOS recognizes the `span` element as a clickable element, as shown in Listing 6-2.

I'm not sure why this "touchmove" handler effects this at all, but following this advice fixed my problem.

That said, there still is about a 0.5-1.0 second delay every time I click before it reacts which really annoys me.  I haven't figured out what causes that.